# WSDL - Trimming?

Tags: wsdl

Is there a way to trim the enterprise WSDL down to a select set of items? We use our WSDL in an ETL tool and due to it's complexity it takes our ETL tool a long time to open the entire tree. I want to get rid of the install packages and such that are shown on the Enterprise WSDL and just get us back to a basic WSDL that has the standard objects and fields along with the custom objects that we have created.

A tool of some type that could verify syntax would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual method is manual editing, although it should be possible to use the Eclipse IDE's WSDL editing mode (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_the_WSDL_Editor) to trim out the extra functions that you don't need. You will still need to take care not to delete dependencies that are actually required, because Eclipse cannot validate what is or isn't necessary directly.

User who is generating enterprise WSDL in your case has access to all the managed packages you are seeing in the wsdl. You should perform the export as the user that has the correct permissions.